# iOS 8 Orientation Landscape status bar issue

Tags: ios, landscape

I'm trying to put the status bar in the right landscape while it is always in the portrait position. Am I doing something wrong?

Or can I run the status bar on the right side landscape on specific page?

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

I have tried this code but it didn't work.

```
.h
    UIViewController *currentVC;
.m

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

    if ( vertical )
    {
        orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

    if (horizontal)
    {
        orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }

    return orientations;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotate");

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your content wrapped in a `UINavigationController`? If so, try subclassing the `UINavigationController` and override `prefersStatusBarHidden`

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

That might work?